# Cannot use import statement outside a module when trying to run compiled application from dist folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, apollo-server

I'm completely lost on what is going wrong here.
It's working just fine using the `npm run dev` command. But after compiling with `tsc` and trying to run the application with `node ./dist/server.js` I'm getting strange import errors.
There are no `.ts` files in the `/dist` folder and I don't understand why it's trying to handle a typescript file from the `/dist` folder.
Running the application with `ts-node ./dist/server.js` does work however.

error I'm getting:

```
(node:32696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\project\src\entities\asset.entity.ts:1
import {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at C:\project\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"
      ],
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
   },
   "exclude": ["node_modules"],
   "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

asset.entity.ts

```
import {
  Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column,
  CreateDateColumn, BaseEntity, UpdateDateColumn, ManyToOne, JoinTable,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import User from './user.entity';

@ObjectType({ description: 'Asset Model' })
@Entity()
export default class Asset extends BaseEntity {
    @Field(() => ID)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
.
.
.
}
```

package.json

```
"name": "API",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "server.js",
   "scripts": {
      "build": "tsc",
      "dev": "tsnd --respawn src/server.ts",
      "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
      "start2": "ts-node ./dist/server.js"
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I am using a `ormconfig.json` file for migrations and I had forgotten to update entities folder from dist to src when developing.

```
{
   "entities": [
      "src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}" <------- This was "dist/**.*.entity{.ts,.js}
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entities",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```